# <iron-list> with grid attribute only shows one item per row

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

I want to use the  item from the Polymer catalog as a grid.
I've set the grid attribute on the list and gave the children a fixed width and height.
However, each row just contains one child.
Here is my code:

This is the container for my custom element, which contains the iron-list

```
<div style="height: 675px;">
    <cit-entity-card-container card-data="[[cardData]]"></cit-entity-card-container>
</div>
```

This is my custom element

```
<dom-module id="cit-entity-card-container">

<style include="cit-shared-styles">
    :host {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        @apply(--layout-wrap);
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: var(--cit-white);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
        display: block;
    }

    iron-list {
        height: 675px;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <iron-list items="[[cardData]]" as="item" grid>
        <template>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">100x100</div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'cit-entity-card-container',

        properties: {
            cardData: {
                type: Array,
                value: function() { return []; }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is how it looks like: [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it
It was simple at the end, but really cost me some nerves.

My iron-list was some versions behind the latest
Updated via bower (bower --force update)
Problem solved